# Summing and counting data based on criteria

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe consisting of three columns: x, ID and date_time.
The “x” column is a recording of a variable x that occurs every five minutes, ID indicate what is being recorded, while date_time indicates when. See a piece of the dataframe below.

From this dataframe I would like to calculate a new dataframe that has seven columns: "Measurement", "ID" and "Date", “x_4_5_night_15min_yes/no”, “x_4_5_night_time_15min”, “x_4_5_night_events_15min”, “x_<4_night_15min”

1. “Measurement”. This column should tell what number measurement this was of a given ID. A measurement starts at 23:00:00 and then runs until 22:59:59 the next day. A measurement however starts at random times and the duration of the first measurement is thus not 24 hours. Neither is the last measurement 24 hours.
2. “ID”. Indicate the ID of a given measurement.
3. Date”. This column should show the date of the last recording in a given  measurement in this format: yyyy.mm.dd.
4. “x_4_5_night_events_15min”. ”. A measurement is divided into a day (7:00:00-22:59:59) and a night (23:00:00-6:59:59). This column should give the number of nocturnal episodes with x between 4 and 5 (both included). However, only periods lasting at least 15 minutes should be counted. E.g. two consecutive recordings between 4 and 5 that are preceded and followed by a recording above 5 should not be included, as x would only have been between 4 and 5 for 10 minutes.
5. “x_4_5_night_15min_yes/no. This column should indicate with a yes (1) or no (0) if x was between 4 and 5 (both included) a given night for a least 15 minutes. Same criteria for understanding 15 minutes apply as described in 4.
6. “x_4_5_night_time_15min”. This column should give the amount of time x was between 4 and 5 (both included) a given night. However, only periods lasting at least 15 minutes should be included. Same criteria for understanding 15 minutes apply as described in 4.
7. “x_<4_night_events _15min”. This column should indicate with a yes (1) or no (0) if x was below 4 a given night for at least 15 minutes. Same criteria for understanding 15 minutes apply as described in 4.

There should be a row for every unique measurement. So far I have a code that returns the columns: "Measurement", "ID" and "Date” correctly:

```
df1$mydate = as.Date(df1$date_time, format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")
df1$tm <- as.numeric(df1$date_time)
df1$dts <- 86400*as.numeric(df1$mydate)
df2 <- df1 %>% 
group_by(ID,mydate) %>% 
transform(date = case_when(((dts-3600)<tm & tm<(dts+82800)) ~paste0(mydate), ((dts+82800)<=tm) ~paste0(mydate+1) )) %>% 
select(ID,date) %>%   
unique() %>% 
group_by(ID) %>% 
mutate(measurement = row_number())
```

however I don’t know how to do the last ones.

Here’s an expected output:

```
expected_output <- read.table(header=TRUE, text ="
                     ID Date          x_4_5_night_events_15min  x_4_5_night_15min_yes/no    x_4_5_night_time_15min  x_<4_night_events_15min
                     12 2020.03.02  0                           0                           0                        0
                     12 2020.03.03  1                           1                           20                      1
                     13 2020.05.09  0                           0                           0                       0
                     14 2020.03.03  2                           1                           40                      0
")
```

And here's the data:

```
structure(list(date_time = c("2020.03.02 22:00:17", "2020.03.02 22:05:17", 
"2020.03.02 22:10:17", "2020.03.02 22:35:17", "2020.03.02 22:40:17", 
"2020.03.02 22:45:17", "2020.03.02 22:50:17", "2020.03.02 22:55:17", 
"2020.03.02 23:00:17", "2020.03.02 23:05:17", "2020.03.02 23:10:17", 
"2020.03.02 23:15:17", "2020.03.02 23:20:17", "2020.03.02 23:25:17", 
"2020.03.02 23:30:17", "2020.03.02 23:35:17", "2020.03.02 23:40:17", 
"2020.03.02 23:45:17", "2020.03.02 23:50:17", "2020.03.02 23:55:17", 
"2020.03.03 00:00:17", "2020.03.03 00:55:17", "2020.03.03 01:00:17", 
"2020.03.03 01:05:17", "2020.03.03 01:10:17", "2020.03.03 01:15:17", 
"2020.03.03 01:20:17", "2020.03.03 01:25:17", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
"2020.05.09 08:44:32", "2020.05.09 08:49:33", "2020.05.09 08:54:33", 
"2020.05.09 08:59:34", "2020.05.09 09:04:34", "2020.05.09 09:09:35", 
"2020.05.09 09:14:35", "2020.05.09 09:19:36", "2020.05.09 09:24:36", 
"2020.05.09 09:29:37", "2020.05.09 09:34:37", "2020.05.09 09:39:38", 
"2020.05.09 09:44:38", "2020.05.09 09:49:39", "2020.05.09 09:54:39", 
"2020.05.09 09:59:40", "2020.03.02 22:40:17", "2020.03.02 22:45:17", 
"2020.03.02 22:50:17", "2020.03.02 22:55:17", "2020.03.02 23:00:17", 
"2020.03.02 23:05:17", "2020.03.02 23:10:17", "2020.03.02 23:15:17", 
"2020.03.02 23:20:17", "2020.03.02 23:25:17", "2020.03.02 23:30:17", 
"2020.03.02 23:35:17", "2020.03.02 23:40:17", "2020.03.02 23:45:17", 
"2020.03.02 23:50:17", "2020.03.02 23:55:17", "2020.03.03 00:00:17", 
"2020.03.03 00:55:17", "2020.03.03 01:00:17", "2020.03.03 01:05:17", 
"2020.03.03 01:10:17"), id = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L), x = c("7.55", "4.55", 
"4.55", "12", "12", "10", "10", "4.3", "", "", "4.3", "4.3", 
"4.3", "", "4.3", "12", "12", "12", "2", "12", "12", "", "8", 
"3", "3", "2", "2", "", "12", "10", "10", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", 
"4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", 
"12", "2", "12", "12", "", "8", "3", "3", "2", "2", "", "12", 
"10", "10", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", "4.3", 
"4.3")), row.names = c(NA, 66L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @AnilGoyal, not sure what you mean. The point of asking this question is to see if anyone can help me out me with a code that provide me with the result I'm looking for.

Comment: how do you get `x_4_5_night_time_15min=55` for `ID 14`, as there are only 8 measurements between 4 & 5.

Comment: Further clarification on criteria's 5, 6 & 7 is required.  Does 15 minutes (in criteria 5, 6, 7) mean consecutive/ contiguous 3 recordings between 4 & 5 as in criteria 4?

Comment: @YBS, you are right, it should be 40 and not 55.  The criteria, in regards to understanding "15 minutes", in 4 apply in 5, 6 and 7 as well. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming your initial dataframe as df11, the code below gives the output as desired. Please note that I have assumed that 15 minutes (in criteria 5, 6, 7) means consecutive/ contiguous 3 recordings between 4 & 5 (less than 4 for #7) as in criteria 4.  I am sure someone else can write much shorter and more elegant code.  For now, I have written it step-by-step, so that you can check each step.

```
df11$xn <- as.numeric(df11$x)
df1 <- df11 %>% transform(xmin = ifelse((xn<4 | xn>5 | is.na(xn)),0,5 ),
                          xlt4 = ifelse((xn>=4 | is.na(xn)),0,1),
                          x45 = ifelse((xn<4 | xn>5 | is.na(xn)),0,1)) 

df1$dateTime = as_datetime(df1$date_time, format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")
df1$mydate = as.Date(df1$date_time, format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")

df1$tm <- as.numeric(df1$dateTime)
df1$dts <- 86400*as.numeric(df1$mydate)

df2 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID,mydate) %>% 
  transform(date = case_when(((dts-3600)<tm & tm<(dts+82800)) ~paste0(mydate), ((dts+82800)<=tm) ~paste0(mydate+1) )) %>% 
  transform(dayrnight = ifelse((tm>=(dts+25200) & tm<(dts+82800) ),'day','night' ) ) # %>% 

df3 <- df2 %>% group_by(ID,date,dayrnight) %>% mutate(x45l1 = lag(x45), x45l2=lag(x45,2), xlt4l1 = lag(xlt4))  %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric , replace_na, replace = 0) %>% 
  mutate(x45cum = ifelse(row_number()>2, cumsum(x45)*x45*x45l1,cumsum(x45)), 
         xlt4cum= ifelse(row_number()>2, cumsum(xlt4)*xlt4*xlt4l1,cumsum(xlt4)) ) %>% 
  mutate(x45event = ifelse((x45cum %% 3) == 0, 1*(x45cum>0),0),
         xlt4event= ifelse((xlt4cum %% 3) == 0, 1*(xlt4cum>0),0)) %>% 
  mutate(x45event_tot = cumsum(x45event), xlt4event_tot = cumsum(xlt4event)) %>% 
  mutate(x45min = cumsum(xmin)*(x45event_tot>0)) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(x45mint = max(x45min), x45eventt = max(x45event_tot), xlt4eventt = max(xlt4event_tot)) %>% 
  mutate(x45_15min_yn = ifelse(x45eventt>0,1,0), xlt4_15min_yn = ifelse(xlt4eventt>0,1,0)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID,date), names_from = dayrnight, values_from = c("x45mint", "x45eventt", "x45_15min_yn", "xlt4_15min_yn")) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric , replace_na, replace = 0) %>% 
  select(ID, date, x_4_5_night_events_15min = x45eventt_night, x_4_5_night_15min_yesorno = x45_15min_yn_night, 
         x_4_5_night_time_15min = x45mint_night, x_lt4_night_events_15min = xlt4_15min_yn_night)
  
 
>  df3
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   ID, date [5]
     ID date       x_4_5_night_events_15min x_4_5_night_15min_yesorno x_4_5_night_time_15min x_lt4_night_events_15min
  <int> <chr>                         <dbl>                     <dbl>                  <dbl>                    <dbl>
1    12 2020-03-02                        0                         0                      0                        0
2    12 2020-03-03                        1                         1                     20                        1
3    13 2020-05-09                        0                         0                      0                        0
4    14 2020-03-02                        0                         0                      0                        0
5    14 2020-03-03                        2                         1                     40                        1
```

Comment: it looks like the code works as it should! Let me just check with a larger dataset. Thank you!